# Gluon Mobile nag screen

Tags: java, android, javafx, gluon-mobile, javafxports

Just a quick question. I made a JavaFX application and I want to get it working on Android. So far the only way I found to get this working is to use Gluon Mobile (JavaFXPorts). However, the free version has a nag screen that pops up every time you open the app, prompting you to buy a license.

Is this screen also going to be popping up for users who download the app in the app store or just for me while I'm working on the app?

Also, if anyone knows another way of getting an existing JavaFX app to Android, I'd love to hear about it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nag screen appears if you don't have a license, both on development and if you release the app to the app stores.

You can avoid this nag screen by getting a license from [here](http://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/buy/). You need at least an “Indie” license to use *Gluon Mobile* without the nag screen.